# 403 forbidden error while POST content - Nexcess server

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I'm running Magento latest version on **Nexcess** server.

I  have created custom module to store template design in database. I'm using PHP code within textarea like,

```
<div> First Name: <?php echo $order->getFirstname?></div>
```

I'm using form Post method. When trying to save data It's throwing 403 Forbidden error. However when i'm adding same content to the CMS Block, CMS Page and transactional emails, it's working fine.

> **Note**: I have changed all file permission to 644 and folder permission
> to 755 except *var* (777) and *media* (777).
>
> Apache mod_security extension is enabled on server. But why different
> behaviour between CMS page and my custom module.

Comment: `Do you have a custom WYSIWYG Editor field in your module ?` behalf of Akhilesh Patel

Comment: I tried with WYSIWYG Editor and Simple textarea. both showing 403 Forbidden Error

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 2):

You may have triggered some Mod Security rules with your custom module.

Try checking your Mod Security logs or disable it and see if it works.

If it's confirmed to be caused by Mod Security, you can either identify the particular rule and disable it or change your codes to workaround the rule.

Comment: I have added my ip to the white list.  And it's working fine. But not able to understand why with CMS it was working fine and not works with other custom module

Comment: You will most likely face the same issues where non-whitelisted IPs (like your visitors or other users) may be blocked by Mod Security. Your custom module's codes must have triggered some Mod Security rules while Magento's code doesn't.